# Why do some authors use terms "non-ascending" and "non-descending" instead of ascending and descending?

Tags: soft-question, definition, math-history

In my math book, everywhere the author has used "non-ascending" instead of descending and "non-descending" instead of ascending.
I was wondering if there is some special meaning or use associated with it? 
Because the way I see it is that it just increases the number of words and wastes ink.

Comment: I was, on more than one occasion, struck by confusion because of this terminology. I still instinctively read 'non-increasing' as 'it's false that it is increasing'. It's really unnecessary to use this terminology as we could (and order theorists do) use 'increasing' for the non-strict inequality and 'strictly increasing' for the strict inequality. Since most of the time we're interested in the non-strict inequality, the typing and space advantages are enormous.

Comment: The terms "non-assending" and "non-decending" allow the output to remain flat for some (or all) time for all time.  For example $f(x) = 3$ is both "non-assending" and "non-decending" and is neither "assending" nor "decending" for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence 2, 2, 2, 3, 4 is not increasing, but it's non-decreasing.

The sequence 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is both increasing and non-decreasing.

Compare the difference between "less than" and "not greater than."

(I have never seen the words ascending/descending used in this context but I imagine it's the same).

Comment: Put differently, "non-decreasing" means "increasing but not necessarily strictly increasing" and "increasing" means "**strictly** increasing", at least for authors using such terminology.